# List all .c/.h dependecies during target build using make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there way to get a report of all dependencies of particular target in GNU makefile?

Comment: If you build the target you can have make print out the `$^` automatic variable: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_005e  Since you don't actually provide any details on why you want this information there's not much else to say.

Comment: Do you mean the directly declared dependencies of a single target, or are you including all *their* dependencies, too, recursively?  Do you mean to include any dependencies that are not explicitly declared?